# Get Leaflet FlyTo callback fucntion

Tags: javascript, leaflet

How can i get leaflet `FlyTo` callback function?

This is my code

```
map.flyTo([lat, lng], zoom);
```

I test this way but not work for me

```
map.flyTo([lat, lng], zoom, function () {

});
```

Comment: There is no callback functionality for `flyTo` - try catching either the `zoomend` or `moveend` events as an alternative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no callback functionality for `flyTo` - try catching either the `zoomend` or `moveend` events as an alternative.

```
map.on('zoomend', function () {
    console.log("callback zoomend")
});
```